# What are these parts on Super Etendard?

Tags: feature-identification

I'm currently working on modelling a [Super Etendard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault-Breguet_Super_%C3%89tendard) and just have a few questions on what are some small parts.

First of all, any ideas what this tube thing is on the right side of the exhaust? My best guess is a fuel dump nozzle but seems like a bit of an odd place?

[image: part]

Next, any ideas what this tube thing is, seems to have a hole in it so maybe some kinda sensor intake or something?

[image: part]

[image: part]

Will most likely have more questions as time goes on but would be good to know what are these things?

EDIT: Also any idea what these bits might be under the wings?
[image: part]
[image: part]

Comment: These drawings may help: [1](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8a/88/a8/8a88a8332751ae810478cf06a6612d21.gif) || [2](http://www.ffaa.net/aircraft/super-etendard/images/super-etendard-0090.jpg) || [3](http://zarco-macross.wdfiles.com/local--files/wiki:super-etendard/0fe98e08eaf73f573e5245e77a43ed45-d3i7jfq.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two objects on the wings are the hooks for the launch bridle, which attaches the aircraft to the catapult shuttle for launching the plane from a carrier deck.

Comment: Ah ye cheers, you see them fall off after CATO :D